# PHP cURL 7.36 error: Error while processing content unencoding: invalid code lengths set

Tags: php, curl, compression, gzip

I've come across a really weird behaviour (bug?) while using curl to download a gzip compressed XML file from PHP. The error message reads :

> Error while processing content unencoding: invalid code lengths set

Weird thing is, **it only happens on my local machine when using curl from PHP**. Running the exact same script on my server will be successful as well as running curl.exe standalone on my local machine (see below for further details on the used systems).

This leads me to believe it might be a bug in the php_curl.dll (curl version 7.36.0).

**Can someone with a similiar setup can confirm this problem?**

---

### Systems

Local PHP setup (error):

- PHP Version: 5.5.11
- curl Version: 7.36.0

  - Host: i386-pc-win32
  - SSL Version: OpenSSL/1.0.1g
  - ZLib Version: 1.2.7
  - libSSH Version: libssh2/1.4.3

Remote PHP setup (works)

- PHP Version: 5.5.16-nmm1
- curl Version: 7.22.0

  - Host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  - SSL Version: OpenSSL/1.0.1
  - ZLib Version: 1.2.3.4
  - libSSH Version: [not installed]

Local standalone curl (works):

- curl Version: 7.37.0 (From [paehl.com](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.37.1))
- curl Version: 7.36.0 (From [npackd.org](http://www.npackd.org/p/se.haxx.curl.CURL/7.36))
- curl Version: 7.30.0 (Came as part of [msysGit](http://msysgit.github.io/))

### Code to reproduce

**From PHP**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.tchibo.de/sitemap-pv-pa.xml");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

if(curl_exec($curl) === false) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else {
    echo 'Success!';
}
curl_close ($curl);
```

will output something like this (when failing):

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 212.116.1.40...
* Connected to www.tchibo.de (212.116.1.40) port 80 (#0)
> GET /sitemap-pv-pa.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tchibo.de
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sitemap-pv-pa.xml"
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Thu, 02 Oct 2014 09:10:58 GMT
< 
* Error while processing content unencoding: invalid code lengths set
* Failed writing data
* Closing connection 0

Error: Error while processing content unencoding: invalid code lengths set
```

**From command line**

> [path to curl.exe] --compress -v "http://www.tchibo.de/sitemap-pv-pa.xml" > tmp.txt

Output (successful)

```
C:\curl-versions\7.36\bin>curl.exe --compress -v "http://www.tchibo.de/sitemap-pv-pa.xml" > tmp.txt
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 212.116.1.40...
* Connected to www.tchibo.de (212.116.1.40) port 80 (#0)
> GET /sitemap-pv-pa.xml HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.36.0
> Host: www.tchibo.de
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sitemap-pv-pa.xml"
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Thu, 02 Oct 2014 09:34:18 GMT
<
{ [data not shown]
100  814k    0  814k    0     0   791k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  803k
* Connection #0 to host www.tchibo.de left intact
```